# remove spaces from csv field but ignoring datetime objec

Tags: python, csv, datetime

i have a csv that is a result of a DB2 query.
For some reason the csv is created like this

```
"filed1     ", "field2,     ","2017-11-24"
```

i'm able to remove the white spaces inside field with this:

```
for result in results:
    result = [x.strip(' ') for x in result]
    csvwriter.writerow(result)
```

but the date field is `<type 'datetime.date'>` so i get the error

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

How can i apply the strip function only to string object? Or can i transform the datetime.date object in str object?

Thanks very much

Comment: You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.  [if Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your list comprehension as follows:

```
result = [str(x).strip() for x in result]
```

This will first convert all the cells to a string and then apply the `strip()` on that. Or more directly as follows:

```
csvwriter.writerow([str(x).strip() for x in result])
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I was doing a stupid error, i was trying with:
result = [str(x.strip()) for x in result]

Answer (score 0):

Just check the type before:

```
if isinstance(x,str):
    ...
```

Comment: Would recommend adding that `isinstance(object, Type)` is "standard" in python3 as it checks if an object is a subtype as well (which if you are not checking for, is normally fair to say something is 'wrong' in your design)